# Override the font size of the android system settings

Tags: android, layout, system, font-size

I've got the problem, if someone edits the font size of the android system (in Settings->Display->Font Size), my app layout doesn't fit anymore. I developed my app in normal font size.

I would like to override the font size of the systems settings just for this app.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this apply to your font size? I thought it would only apply to textsize atributes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to override the font size of the systems settings just for this app.

That is not strictly possible. Anything measured in `sp` will take the font scaling into account.

Your short-term solution will be to change those dimensions to `dp`, as 1 `sp` equals 1 `dp` at normal font scale.

That being said, please consider updating your UI to be more flexible about font scale, as that is important for some users, whose vision is not as acute.

Comment: can i override system fonts too, i want my app to have its specific fonts and not system fonts

Comment: @FemnDharamshi: There are a variety of solutions for using custom fonts within your own activities. This includes the font resource support added to Android last year, plus older solutions like the Calligraphy library.